# in php Foreach loop moves to the wrong key

Tags: php

I have the following array structure

```
jobs =  {70811 ={....invoices = { A="A",...},...},...}
```

Then I have two nested loops.  The outer nested loop seeks each job # in this case 70811.  The inner loop then seeks each invoice listed for the job.

in each loop I query one of the tables

```
foreach ($this->p['jobs'] as $job => $value) {
    $sql = 'select concat(sum(i.`AMOUNT`))as `amount`, ...
            from `invoice` i
            where  i.`JOBID` = '.$job.'
            group by i.`tracknum` = "'.$this->cTrackKey.'"';

    $cmeJobEdits = 0;
    if ($result = $db->query($sql))
    {
        if ($result->num_rows > 0)
        {
            $this->budget = mysqli_fetch_all( $result, $resulttype = MYSQLI_ASSOC );

            $subTot = 0;
            for ($i=0; $i<count($this->budget);$i++)
            {
                $subTot += $this->budget[$i]['amount'];
            }
            ...
            unset($i);
            $xsql = 'update `cmejob` set `balance` = '.$this->budget[0]['balance'].',... where `jobid` = '.$job;
            if (!$result = $db->query($xsql))
            {
                throw new Exception("Query to update budget failed!");
            }else{
                $cmeJobEdits++;
            }
            unset($xsql);
        }
    }else{
        throw new Exception("Query to get billed amounts for this job failed! "`enter code here`);
    }
    unset($sql);
    unset($value);
}//end loop updating cme jobs
```

My problem is this the outer query where the $job variable is not the next job # but the nested array key "invoices" as shown below.

As shown in the code I tried unsetting the query and key variables in the loops with no success.

```
select concat(sum(i.`AMOUNT`))as `amount`, ...
from `invoice` i
where  i.`JOBID` = invoices //this is the value of the variable $job
group by i.`tracknum` = "'.$this->cTrackKey.'"';
```

Comment: Why do you call `CONCAT()` with just one argument?

Comment: I don't see how this could happen if the data is as you show. Please post `var_dump($this->p['jobs']);`.

Comment: I added the concat() just to get a label for the column.  Will post the var_dump

Comment: `AS amount` gives you a label for the column, you don't need `CONCAT()`. Just write `SELECT SUM(i.amount) AS amount`.

Comment: array(1) {
  [84528]=>
  array(6) {
    ["thisBudget"]=>
    string(4) "0.00"
    ["thisBilled"]=>
    string(9) "44,633.80"
    ["thisSum"]=>
    string(9) "28,003.00"
    ["thisBalance"]=>
    string(10) "-72,636.80"
    ["invoices"]=>
    array(1) {
      ["A"]=>
      string(1) "A"
    }
    ["DORMANT"]=>
    string(0) ""
  }
}

Comment: Put it in the question so you can format it.

Comment: The reference label I get with just the sum is "sum(i.amount).  I was looking for a simple label saying just amount.  But not really the issue here.  I'm still stuck on the fact my loop grabs an array with an array

Comment: I know it's not the issue, but that shouldn't happen if you add an alias with `AS`. Are you sure the code you posted is the code you're actually running? I suspect you've edited it, and that's causing these differences.

Comment: Yes of course, thanks I should have read your original post more carefully. Appreciate the hint.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the var_dump($this->p['jobs'] of the values as you requested. Is this how you prefer seeing it

```
array(1) { [84528]=> array(6) { ["thisBudget"]=> string(4) "0.00" ["thisBilled"]=> string(9) "44,633.80" ["thisSum"]=> string(9) "28,003.00" ["thisBalance"]=> string(10) "-72,636.80" ["invoices"]=> array(1) { ["A"]=> string(1) "A" } ["DORMANT"]=> string(0) "" } }
```

Comment: As shown here the outer object has just one entry "array(1)" value 84528.  The inner object has 6 elements of which one is "invoices".  The problem for me is the outer loop goes around twice and inserts "invoices" as the 2nd value for the outer loop query.

Answer (score 0):

The problem has been resolved.

As usual the error occurred in code not shown.  The code above added an 'invoices' element to the $this->p['jobs'] array when it should have been added somewhere else.

now the loop works as described.